# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown layer

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I am following an [image classification tutorial from google](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification). At some point, there are some data augmentation that are done: `RandomFlip`, `RandomRotation`, `RandomZoom`.

When done with the training, I exported the model using `tfjs.converters.save_keras_model` to be used in my node application. At node start, I get this error:

> ***Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown layer: RandomFlip. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
> The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
> The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().***

I read somewhere that I could edit the model.json file in some ways to make it work. But I don't know how to apply it to these three transformations. Here is the first lines of the modej.json file:

```
    {"format": "layers-model", "generatedBy": "keras v2.4.0", "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v2.4.0", "modelTopology": {"keras_version": "2.4.0", "backend": "tensorflow", "model_config": {"class_name": "Sequential", "config": {"name": "sequential_2", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 200, 200, 3], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "sequential_1_input"}}, {"class_name": "Sequential", "config": {"name": "sequential_1", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 200, 200, 3], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "random_flip_input"}}, {"class_name": "RandomFlip", "config": {"name": "random_flip", "trainable": true, "batch_input_shape": [null, 200, 200, 3], "dtype": "float32", "mode": "horizontal", "seed": null}}, {"class_name": "RandomRotation", "config": {"name": "random_rotation", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "factor": 0.1, "fill_mode": "reflect", "interpolation": "bilinear", "seed": null}}, {"class_name": "RandomZoom", "config": {"name": "random_zoom", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "height_factor": 0.1, "width_factor": null, "fill_mode": "reflect", "interpolation": "bilinear", "seed": null}}]}}, {"class_name": "Rescaling", "config": {"name": "rescaling_2", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "scale": 0.00392156862745098, "offset": 0.0}}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "conv2d_3", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "filters": 16, "kernel_size": [
```

Any way to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Change `modelTopology.model_config.class_name` from `Sequential` to `Model`.

```
 {"format": "layers-model", "generatedBy": "keras v2.4.0", "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v2.4.0", "modelTopology": {"keras_version": "2.4.0", "backend": "tensorflow", "model_config": {"class_name": "Model", "config": {"name": "sequential_2", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 200, 200, 3], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "sequential_1_input"}}, {"class_name": "Sequential", "config": {"name": "sequential_1", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 200, 200, 3], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "random_flip_input"}}, {"class_name": "RandomFlip", "config": {"name": "random_flip", "trainable": true, "batch_input_shape": [null, 200, 200, 3], "dtype": "float32", "mode": "horizontal", "seed": null}}, {"class_name": "RandomRotation", "config": {"name": "random_rotation", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "factor": 0.1, "fill_mode": "reflect", "interpolation": "bilinear", "seed": null}}, {"class_name": "RandomZoom", "config": {"name": "random_zoom", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "height_factor": 0.1, "width_factor": null, "fill_mode": "reflect", "interpolation": "bilinear", "seed": null}}]}}, {"class_name": "Rescaling", "config": {"name": "rescaling_2", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "scale": 0.00392156862745098, "offset": 0.0}}, {"class_name": "Conv2D", "config": {"name": "conv2d_3", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "filters": 16, "kernel_size": [
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Please note that I couldn't see "modelTopology.model_config.class_name" in the model.json file. That being said, when I change "sequential" in the line, I started getting the following:

Comment: "t.inboundNode not defined"

Comment: It is right there in the the one you attached in the question. I updated the answer with it.

Comment: I did it, but it doesnt even load the model; in console, I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.inboundNodes is undefined

Comment: Could you include the code for loading in the model?

Comment: Any updates? I do have the same error. 

I’ve first trained the model using the Python api and then converted it as tfjs model, but in my JavaScript app using the ml5 APIs it doesn’t work.